# Fetch start and end datetime while values are zero

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, numpy

I would like to fetch the start datetime and end datetime while the value of data is zero.
The data is in Postgresql.
If I get the Postgresql solution much help full or Python using numpy or pandas.
for example

column 1 will contain datetime
column 2 will contain values.

```
DateTime    Value
06-07-2021 12:00    -521362.8779
06-07-2021 12:15    -57275.52732
06-07-2021 12:30    0
06-07-2021 12:45    0
06-07-2021 13:00    0
06-07-2021 13:15    0
06-07-2021 13:30    0
06-07-2021 13:45    0
06-07-2021 14:00    -57275.52732
06-07-2021 14:15    -377411.4886
06-07-2021 14:30    -377411.4886
06-07-2021 14:45    0
06-07-2021 15:00    0
06-07-2021 15:15    0
06-07-2021 15:30    -889863.5254
06-07-2021 15:45    -1194683.49
06-07-2021 16:00    0
06-07-2021 16:15    0
06-07-2021 16:30    0
06-07-2021 16:45    0
06-07-2021 17:00    -89539.05766
06-07-2021 17:15    -1117269.624
06-07-2021 17:30    -857357.2725
```

The required output shall be
Column 1 serial no,
Column 2 Start DateTime,
Column 3 End DateTime

```
Serial No   Start DateTime  End DateTime
1   06-07-2021 12:30    06-07-2021 13:45
2   06-07-2021 14:45    06-07-2021 15:15
3   06-07-2021 16:00    06-07-2021 16:45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the type of your DateTime column is already `datetime` or you transform your above string into a `dataframe` using

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df_string), sep='\s{2,}',engine='python',parse_dates=['DateTime'])
```

then you do

```
x = df['Value'].to_numpy()
mask = np.empty(x.shape[0], 'bool')
mask[0] = x[0] == 0
mask[1:] = (x[1:] == 0)  & (x[:-1] != 0)

mask2 = np.empty(x.shape[0], 'bool')
mask2[-1] = x[0] == 0
mask2[:-1] = (x[1:] != 0)  & (x[:-1] == 0)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Start': df['DateTime'][mask].reset_index(drop=True),
              'End' :df['DateTime'][mask2].reset_index(drop=True)})
```

and you get

```
                Start                 End
0 2021-06-07 12:30:00 2021-06-07 13:45:00
1 2021-06-07 14:45:00 2021-06-07 15:15:00
2 2021-06-07 16:00:00 2021-06-07 16:45:00
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer works perfectly, I will have to study more on numpy mask.

Answer (score 0):

I just compare the current row with next/previous row values. If one is zero and the other is not, then it's a Start or End.
You can use the shift method to shift the rows.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Start DateTime'] = (
    df[(df['Value'] == 0) & (df['Value'].shift() != 0)]
    ['DateTime'].reset_index(drop=True) )
df1['End DateTime'] = (
    df[(df['Value'] == 0) & (df['Value'].shift(-1) != 0)]
    ['DateTime'].reset_index(drop=True))
```

|  | Start DateTime | End DateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 06-07-2021 12:30 | 06-07-2021 13:45 |
| 1 | 06-07-2021 14:45 | 06-07-2021 15:15 |
| 2 | 06-07-2021 16:00 | 06-07-2021 16:45 |

Comment: Thank you, your answer also works perfectly for me. But, I have to accept the first person answer as a first come.

Comment: @BhuvanKumar  That's alright !!!

Comment: What if the values start in zero but don't end in zero? Isn't that a special case you have to handle?